# How to get category names in post_class?

Tags: categories, post-class

I have this class for my posts:

```
<?php post_class( 'entry-image' ); ?>
```

I want to add the **category names** to get isotope work, i followed this guide http://www.acegoulet.com/2012/03/isotope-and-wordpress-how-i-did-it/ and i used this code to get category names:

```
$post_cats = get_the_category(); foreach( $post_cats as $category ) { echo $category->slug.' ';}
```

but this doesn't work.
I tried to add a comma between the class and the category:

```
<?php post_class( 'entry-image', $post_cats = get_the_category(); foreach( $post_cats as $category ) { echo $category->slug.' ';} ); ?>
```

I checked the firebug but I don't see category name in loops (posts).
Why this doesn't work?

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the values, not `echo` them.

So something like this should work:

```
$post_cats = get_the_category();
$slugs = wp_list_pluck( $post_cats, 'slug' );
post_class( join( ' ', $slugs );
```